# Service openfire startup with script openfire.sh

Tags: openfire

look, always should run this command:

```
# cd /opt/openfire/bin/
# ./openfire.sh  start
Openfire 3.6.4 [19-may-2009 17:43:25]
Console d'administration en écoute sur:
http://server.xxxxx.com:9090
https://server.xxxxx.com:9091
Index opened.
Index thread started
```

If I close the putty command line… the service openfire down… and after is neccessary again run… somebody know some way for always this service are permanently up ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All of the Openfire distributions should come with some kind of daemon or service script. It's hard to tell exactly what operating system you're on, but try typing something like this:

```
service openfire start
```

Also, I'm noticing that you're using a *very old* version of Openfire (it's from 2009!). I urge you to upgrade. Not only were many improvements and new features added, but security has been improved greatly over the years too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know it's an old version of openfire. but the service does not start with the command  service openfire start .it starts just with the script /openfire.sh  which is in /opt/openfire/bin/
knowing that it is installed with xampp.